# Should I bother cleaning up this query, or MariaDB handles this for me?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am generating some MySQL queries using php. In some cases, my code generates duplicate query code for some of the queries, for security precautions. For example, let's say I have a table `UploadedImages`, which contains images uploaded by a user. It is connected to the `User` table via a reference. When a plain user wants to query that table, if he doesn't have admin rights, I forcefully put in a `WHERE` condition to the query, which only retrieves images which belong to him.

Because of this forcefull inclusion, sometimes, the query which I generate results in duplicate where conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM UploadedImages WHERE 
  accounts_AccountId = '143' AND 
  DateUploaded > '2017-10-11 21:42:32' AND 
  accounts_AccountId = '143'
```

Should I bother, with cleaning up this query before running it, or will `MariaDB` clean it up for me? (ie, will this query run any slower, or is it possible that it will result in erroneus results if I don't clean it up beforehand, by removing the identical duplicate conditions?)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "Should I bother cleaning it up?", Yes you should clean up the code that produces this because the fact that it can include the same clause multiple times suggests the database layer is not abstracted to a particularly modern level. The database layer should be able to be re-written to use a different database provider without having to change the code that depends upon it. It looks like it is not the case.

If your question is "Does adding the same restriction twice slow the query?" then the answer is no, not significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer the question for yourself:  Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on both queries.  If the output is the same, then the dup was cleaned up.